# What is the song in Naruto Shippuden that plays in episode 3 at 7:45?

Tags: naruto, music

The song occurs at 7:45 after Sakura punches the ground when trying to find Kakashi. It also occurs in several other episodes but I cannot find the OST.

Can someone help me find this?

Answer (score 2):

A fire inside by Yasuharu Takanashi.
All complement to shazam.
Didn't find it on youtube but [this](https://ai-ringtones.com/ringtones/75778) might help